# Change displayed sheet after user inactivity

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a piece of code that links to a certain sheet after a certain amount of time of inactivity, what I mean by inactivity is not switching through sheets, so when somebody is clicking on sheets that counts as activity but as soon as its been on the same sheet for an amount of time I want it to switch to sheet 1 (sheet 1 is linked to a presentation and will act much like a screensaver would)

Here is my code in ThisWorkbook

```
Private nTime As Date

Const proc As String = "SelectIndex"

Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Source As Range)

    Call SetTimer

End Sub



Private Sub SetTimer()

    If nTime <> 0 Then

    Call Application.OnTime(EarliestTime:=nTime, Procedure:=proc, Schedule:=False)

    End If

    nTime = Now + TimeValue("00:00:05")

    Application.OnTime nTime, Procedure:=proc

End Sub
```

This works for entering data, when somebody doesn’t enter data for so long it goes to my sheet, but I want it to do it if somebody isn’t switching sheets because nobody has access to enter data anyway, just view the sheets.

It also only works once, when you cancel the presentation and try it again I get the error

> "Run time error '1004' Method 'OnTime' of object '_ Application'
>   Failed "

Just these two problems to overcome and I would really appreciate it if anyone could help J

For information, the procedure `SelectIndex` is just a macro that switches to sheet 1

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, you could trigger the timer within the `Sheet_Activate` event:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    Call SetTimer   
End Sub
```

Comment: Here's his reply:
That works for the first time, it pops up with the presentation 5 seconds after no sheet activity, the only problem is that when I click a sheet a second time it pops up with the error message, 

"Run time error '1004'
Method 'OnTime' of object '_ Application' Failed "

It has something to do with 

Call Application.OnTime(EarliestTime:=nTime, Procedure:=proc, Schedule:=False)
But I have no idea

Comment: Update: It works fine just as long as I am on the sheet with the presentation, but if I am on a different page it doesn’t work and I get the error

Comment: Right, it's been fixed. Thanks for your help JMax. Here's the working code:


Private nTime As Date

Const proc As String = "SelectIndex"

Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)

Call SetTimer

End Sub

Private Sub SetTimer()

On Error Resume Next

    If nTime Then


        Call Application.OnTime(EarliestTime:=nTime, Procedure:=proc, Schedule:=False)

    End If

    nTime = Now + TimeValue("00:00:10")


    Application.OnTime nTime, Procedure:=proc

End Sub

Comment: Eek! That's unreadable. Put it in the question body, properly `formatted!`

Comment: @user1587320: Glad you solved your issue. You can post this code in another answer and accept it after the delay, that would be helpful for fellow users and searchers. Thanks